# api call using php cURL not returning all pages

Tags: php, api, curl

I'm trying to hit an api and populate a database table with the returned data. There are over 9000 rows of data I need to get, and only 100 rows of data per page. I'm setting up loops, to control which page I'm at, but only the first 100 records (first page) gets returned.

My code currently is only grabbing two pages for testing.

I'm using PHP cURL to accomplish this

```
for($pageLoop = 0; $pageLoop < 2; $pageLoop++){
  $curl2 = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($curl2, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://SOME_SERVER/rest/search/?api_key=MY_API_KEY&searchTerm=&pageNumber=".$pageLoop."&pageSize=100",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      "cache-control: no-cache"
    ),
  ));

  $response2 = curl_exec($curl2);
  $err2= curl_error($curl2);

  if(!curl_exec($curl2)){
    die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl2) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl2));
  }
  curl_close($curl2);

  for($itemLoop = 0; $itemLoop <  100; $itemLoop++){
    echo 'chpl product number yy: ' . $response['results'][$itemLoop]['chplProductNumber'] . '<br>';
  }//END ITEM LOOP        
}//END PAGE LOOP
```

Expected results are a list of items for each page. There are 97 pages total as of today and I'm only getting the first page. 
Thanks

Comment: `$pageLoop` starts at 0, and you are using that variable in the URL. Does page 0 exist?

Comment: Yes, it does exist.

Comment: Is page 1 identical to page 0? I've never seen api pagination start at 0 before, my guess is 0 is returning no results, and page 1 is returning results. Hence only getting the first page. Checkout my answer to see what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is, you are calling page 0 which doesn't return any results. So then on your second iteration, you are calling page 1 for the first time.

Hence, only getting first page result.

Try this:

```
$pageLoop = 1;
do {
  $cl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt_array($cl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://SOME_SERVER/rest/search/?api_key=MY_API_KEY&searchTerm=&pageNumber=".$pageLoop."&pageSize=100",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
      "cache-control: no-cache"
    ),
  ));

  $response = curl_exec($cl);
  curl_close($cl);

  for($itemLoop = 0; $itemLoop <  100; $itemLoop++)
    echo 'chpl product number yy: ' . $response['results'][$itemLoop]['chplProductNumber'] . '<br>';

  $pageLoop++;
} while ($pageLoop <= 2);
```

Also, I notice a few variable names which are completely unused. for example `$err2` and `$response2`. My latest edit cleans that up a bit.

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. In fact page zero exists. I can see it when running it through postman. Also, your code returned an empty response.

Comment: This is what I noticed. The cURL code doesn't work inside the loop. The page URL gets updated with the new page number, but the response variable still holds values from the first page even when the call is for page 2